# IP packets can get dropped with TCP payloads?

Tags: ip, tcp

TCP segment encapsulate it IP payload,if some way ip packet is lost in transmission.

some time IP packet will be fragmented,

i ask if this one fragment part will be lost in transmission.how can fix it?

all other packet will be drop?

Comment: At least I have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: It is still not clear what you’re asking

Comment: fragmented ip packet,if drop in transmission TCP payload already drop??

Comment: Still no luck.. i dont get it.

Comment: TCP segment go inside IP packets,there are many problems.ip packets can get dropped with TCP payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a fragment of a packet gets lost, the destination host will be unable to rebuild the packet, and the packet will be discarded.

IP is connectionless, and it has no facility to request missing fragments or packets. Upper-layer protocols or applications must request any missing packets to be resent, if necessary (for some protocols or applications, e.g. real-time, resending old data can be a bad thing). Connection-oriented protocols, e.g. TCP, will request any missing data, but connectionless protocols, e.g. UDP will not request missing data, so it would be up to the application or application-layer protocol to request missing data.

Comment: Any fragment part lost TCP help to request them again?

Comment: this is missing fragment of a packet or sender ip packet?

Comment: If a packet is dropped, then TCP would not get the segment that is the payload of the packet. TCP guarantees in-order data delivery, and it has a mechanism to request missing segment be resent from the source TCP.

Comment: it's helpful answer